# How should I integrate auto complete code into my current AngularJS code in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm a very newbie to AngularJS, so please try to understand my concerns.

I already have an HTML page and a controller written for it as follows :

**bankDetails.html**

```
<!-- Main -->
<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-gt-sm="column"
    layout-md="row" layout-xs="column" layout-lg="row"
    style="margin-bottom: 1em" class="user-settings">
    <!-- First Column -->
    <div layout-align="center" layout="column" flex="100">
        <div layout-align="center" flex="100">
            <div class="singleColumnUserSettings">
                <form name="bankDetailsForm" action="save" method="POST"
                    ng-init="getBankDetails()">

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:1em;">
                    <label>Current Account Label</label> <input
                        ng-model="bankDetails.currentAccountLabel" required
                        name="currentAccountLabel" ng-change="editField()">
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.currentAccountLabel.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid Bank account
                            Label</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <label>Bank Name</label> <input ng-model="bankDetails.bankName"
                        required name="bankName" ng-change="editField()">
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.bankName.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid Bank name</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <label>Branch</label> <input ng-model="bankDetails.branch" required
                        name="branch" ng-change="editField()">
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.branch.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid Branch</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <label>IFSC Code</label> <input ng-model="bankDetails.ifscCode"
                        required name="ifscCode" ng-change="editField()">
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.ifscCode.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid IFSC code</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <label>Account Number</label> <input
                        ng-model="bankDetails.accountNumber" required
                        name="accountNumber" ng-change="editField()">
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.accountNumber.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid Bank account
                            number</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;"
                        flex=100> <label>Transaction Type</label> <md-select
                        required ng-model="bankDetails.transactionType" ng-change="editField()"> <md-option
                        ng-repeat="type in transactionTypes" value="{{type}}">
                    {{type}} </md-option> </md-select>
                    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.transactionType.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Please select Transaction type</div>
                    </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-button style="width:30%; display: block;margin:3em auto auto;"
                        ng-disabled="bankDetailsForm.$invalid" id="save" ng-click="save()"
                        class="md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Column-->

    <div layout-align="center" layout="column" flex="100">
        <div layout-align="center end" flex="100">
            <div class="singleColumnRightUserSettings">

                <md-content layout-padding>

                <form name="masterUserSettingsUploadFile" action="save"
                    method="POST">

                    <md-radio-group ng-model="data.documentType" class="textSizeMedium">
                    <div layout="row" style="margin-top: 0.5em;" flex=100>
                        <md-radio-button value="Cancelled & crossed Cheque"
                            style="margin-top: 0.8em;"> <b>Cancelled &
                            crossed Cheque</b> </md-radio-button>
                        <p style="margin-left: 1em;" class="textSizeSmall">-
                            Organization name printed on same</p>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="row">
                        <md-radio-button value="A Nodal Bank Letter"
                            style="margin-top: 1em;"> <b>A Nodal Bank
                            Letter</b> </md-radio-button>
                        <p style="margin-left: 1em;" class="textSizeSmall">- Stating
                            your current account details</p>
                    </div>

                    </md-radio-group>
                    <div layout="row" flex="100" style="margin-top: 1em;">
                        <input style="display: none;"
                            on-read-file="uploadFile($fileContent)" type="file"
                            name="file-6[]" id="file-6" class="inputfile inputfile-5"
                            data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple /> <label
                            for="file-6"> <i class="material-icons uploadFile"
                            style="margin-left: -0.8em;">insert_drive_file</i> <span></span></label>
                        <span class="radioValue textSizeSmall" style="margin-top: 0.8em;"
                            flex=50>{{ data.documentType }} </span>
                        <div layout="row" layout-align="right">
                            <md-button class="md-icon-button"> <i
                                class="material-icons uploadFile">delete</i></md-button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <md-content class="messageBorder"
                        style="background-color:#FFC1C1;border-radius:5px;margin-top:1em;">
                    <label class="textSizeSmall">We would request you to please
                        send us all the documents Self Attested (Signature and Company
                        Stamp). Please use the sign which is matching with your ID proof
                        provided.</label> </md-content>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**bankDetailsController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app_name');
var isEmpty = true;

app.controller("bankDetailsController", [ "$scope", "$http", "config", "$mdToast",
        function($scope, $http, config, $mdToast) {
            $scope.bankDetails = {};
            $scope.transactionTypes = {
                NEFT : "NEFT",
                IMPS : "IMPS",
                WALLET : "WALLET",
            };

            $scope.getBankDetails = function() {
                $http.get(config.webServicesUrl.bankDetails, headerConfig).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.body) {
                        $scope.bankDetails.currentAccountLabel = data.body.currentAccountLabel;
                        $scope.bankDetails.bankName = data.body.bankName;
                        $scope.bankDetails.branch = data.body.branch;
                        $scope.bankDetails.ifscCode = data.body.ifcsCode;
                        $scope.bankDetails.accountNumber = data.body.accountNumber;
                        //$scope.bankDetails.transactionTypes[NEFT] = $scope.transactionTypes.NEFT;
                        isEmpty = false;
                    }
                }).error(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error : " + error.error);
                });
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                var bankDetails = {
                    currentAccountLabel : $scope.bankDetails.currentAccountLabel,
                    bankName : $scope.bankDetails.bankName,
                    branch : $scope.bankDetails.branch,
                    ifcsCode : $scope.bankDetails.ifscCode,
                    accountNumber : $scope.bankDetails.accountNumber,
                    transactionType : "NEFT",
                };
                if (isEmpty) {
                    $http.post(config.webServicesUrl.bankDetails, bankDetails, headerConfig).success(function(data) {
                        displayToastMessage("Your details saved successfully", $mdToast);
                        $( "#save" ).prop( "disabled", true );
                        isEmpty = false;
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error : " + error.error);
                    });
                } else {
                    $http.put(config.webServicesUrl.bankDetails, bankDetails, headerConfig).success(function(data) {
                        displayToastMessage("Your details saved successfully", $mdToast);
                        $( "#save" ).prop( "disabled", true );
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error : " + error.error);
                    });
                }
            }
            $scope.editField = function() {
                // Enable save button after user starts editing
                $( "#save" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            };
            $scope.data = {
                documentType : 'Cancelled & crossed Cheque'
            };

        } ]);
```

Now ignore all the code and concentrate only on the input field for IFSC code. I want to make this input field auto complete enabled. For it I referred following link

[Autocomplete basic Usage in Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

I want to implement the same code into my code on the field for IFSC code.
But since my controller file already contains a controller where should I write the JS code from link and what changes do I need to make in HTML code?

I've become clueless now. Please somebody help me out.

Thanks.

**P.S. :** All the necessary CSS and JS files have been already included in config file to use Angular Material in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example.

```
 <md-autocomplete required 
                  md-selected-item="selectedCode"
                  md-search-text="bankDetails.ifscCode"
                  md-items="temp in editField(bankDetails.ifscCode)"
                  md-item-text="temp.text"
                  placeholder="IFSC Code">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="search" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{temp.text}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        No states matching "{{bankDetails.ifscCode}}" were found.                            
    </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

here, `md-selected-item` represents the the value you will select after showing the result.

`md-search-text` stores the text you write in the box.

`md-items` will be responsible for showing result depending upon the query. It will use a searchFunction which will be written in the controller. For Example,

```
$scope.editField = editField ;
editField = function(query){
   //use $http service to query server and resolve this promise and return  object or array to iterate.
};
```

`md-item-text` will display the text.
`md-item-template` is a template for each item returned by `md-items`.

`md-not-found` will display the message it there are no match found.
There are many other options available too. check out the offical documentation for more details.

Comment: I know the example from the link I given in the question. I want to integrate the same in my code. Please provide me solution for it. Thanks.

Comment: You can place the html code in your html file and create appropriate `$scope` variables.

Comment: @user2839497 any update implementing the above code?